# Javascript - Prototype is not reading constructor variables

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I am having issues accessing public variables from an object in a prototyped function... from what I have read, this should work, but perhaps someone with a more experienced eye can point out what I am doing wrong.

In this, I am trying to write my own animation object, with self deletion that another manager can use. callback is a command written as a string, x&y are starting position, x2,&y2 are ending position, time is time in seconds, and element is the element that moves. doTime is the result of a benchmark function that executes on page load to correctly set the timeOut offset.

I can create a working version with inside functions, but as this object is created several times, I was wanting to prototype the function to improve creation speed.

Test show that none of the this.vars are reading within the prototype function.

```
function circDelta(progress) {
    if (progress < .5)
        return (1 - Math.sin(Math.acos(progress))) / 2
    else
        return (2 - (1 - Math.sin(Math.acos(2*(1-progress))))) / 2
}

function animation(element,x,y,x2,y2,time,callback){
    this.e = element;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.t = time * 1000;
    this.c = callback;
    this.cT = 0;
    this.id = setTimeout(this.frame, doTime);
}

animation.prototype.frame = function(){
    this.cT+=doTime;
    if(this.cT>=this.t)
    {
        this.e.style.left = this.x2+'px';
        this.e.style.top = this.y2+'px';
        if(typeof this.c === 'function')
            this.c();
    }
    else
    {
        this.e.style.left = ((this.x2-this.x)*circDelta(this.t/this.cT))+this.x+'px';
        this.e.style.top = ((this.y2-this.y)*circDelta(this.t/this.cT))+this.y+'px';
        this.id = setTimeout(this.frame, doTime);
    }
};
```

I am using the function like this:

```
this.curr_anim = new animation(hC.menus[0],0,0,0,30,1.5,hC.anim_finished);
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.... Thank you in advance.

Comment: `delete this` will not do anything; you can only `delete` properties of objects, not variables.

Comment: Also, no need to wrap `this.c` in a `new Function`; just do `this.c()`.

Comment: Also, your test can become simply `if (typeof this.c === "function")` instead of the three-part test you have currently.

Comment: The last two comments assume you stop passing strings to `new animation`; instead pass the function directly, i.e. `new animation(..., hC.anim_finished)`.

Comment: hC is actually the object calling the function, I did try this.anim_finished(), but that didn't seem to take.

Comment: `hc.anim_finished` will take; don't include the parentheses. That way you are passing the function, not its return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will probably having scoping issues in `setInterval` call,

because setInterval will be called after specified interval and with the scope of window object so it will not be able to access object data using this,

so you need to pass reference of object using a local variable, you can achive this by use of closures in setInterval like this

```
var me = this;
this.id = setTimeout(function() {
    me.frame();
}, doTime);
```

so your final code will look like this

```
function circDelta(progress) {
    if (progress < .5)
        return (1 - Math.sin(Math.acos(progress))) / 2
    else
        return (2 - (1 - Math.sin(Math.acos(2*(1-progress))))) / 2
}

function animation(element,x,y,x2,y2,time,callback){
    this.e = element;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.t = time * 1000;
    this.c = callback;
    this.cT = 0;

    var me = this;
    this.id = setTimeout(function() {
          me.frame();
    }, doTime);
}

animation.prototype.frame = function(){
    this.cT+=doTime;
    if(this.cT>=this.t)
    {
        this.e.style.left = this.x2+'px';
        this.e.style.top = this.y2+'px';
        if(typeof this.c === 'function')
            this.c();
    }
    else
    {
        this.e.style.left = ((this.x2-this.x)*circDelta(this.t/this.cT))+this.x+'px';
        this.e.style.top = ((this.y2-this.y)*circDelta(this.t/this.cT))+this.y+'px';

        var me = this;
        this.id = setTimeout(function() {
             me.frame();
        }, doTime);
    }
};
```